# When demoing a performance improvement, should you demo the speedup first or last?

Tags: communication, presentations

I have a sitewide speedup to demo at work (I just turned on React's code splitting). Page loads go from four seconds to two, Lighthouse performance goes from 38 to 74, code coverage goes from mostly red to nicely siloed. I want to show my manager and team for approval, then include it in the biweekly demo for the customer later.

In the spirit of "tell them what you're going to tell them", should I show the difference between before and after on the live site first, then get into the implementation details? Or should I save it for the end? Given that other people are not as impatient as I am about slow loads, they may not be impressed if I build up to it first.

It should only take a few minutes to demo, so does it even matter whether I show the results first or last?

Comment: Ironically, worrying about this is a waste of your time. Just demo both in whatever order you want. I'm not sure what "nicely soloed" means though.

Comment: Siloed -- in a source-map-explorer chart like https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/7252454/71998874-f1a4ee80-3272-11ea-9369-1bc7a4dbed4e.png, only one section of the source map is loaded, the part that we use, and the rest is left white and undisturbed.

If it didn't matter what order you show things in, the advice "tell them what you're going to tell them" wouldn't exist in the first place. There's always an optimal way, whether it's "describe the problem so they understand the solution", or "show the solution so they want to understand the problem." Steve Jobs would have an opinion.

Comment: Do you tie the shoes on your left shoe first, or your right shoe? Which do you do first, and why? Your demo takes 4 seconds at most. Either way you do it, the contrast is going to be very obvious. I fail to see how Steve Jobs is relevant.

Comment: Steve Jobs knew how to do a demo so people would clap at the end, instead of taking four seconds to say "Look, you can swipe now" and going home. I was going to belabor this out to 3-4 minutes by showing the metrics and graphics so my manager would let me do it and because I thought they made flashy demo content.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Always lead with the headline

When giving a presentation, writing a paper, conveying information to another human, assume you have their attention for about 10 seconds and after that they are going to lose interest if you don't give them a reason to care. People are going to listen to the very first thing you say and make a decision  on whether they want to pay attention to the rest.

Assume the first thing you say is the part they will remember.

#### So what are you trying to say?

Reading your question, I see main 2 ideas for the presentation you want to give:

1. Using the React code splitting feature
2. Hey, the site runs faster now

You need to figure our which one is more important for the presentation you want to give. It really is up to you. Consider what your audience wants to hear about too.

*I want to show off how React code splitting improves the code, and oh by the way, look how fast the site is now.*

Show the code first. Then show off the results.

*I want people to see how fast I made the site run, and here's how I did it*

Show the site first. Then get into the details.

Know what you want to say. Know what your audience wants to hear. Lead with the headline.

Comment: I kind of lost sight of the pyramid principle because of something I read about the Promised Land structure. This is wise and makes #2 an easy choice in my case.

Comment: @Noumenon, I'm guessing from its name that Promised Land is a structure where you take the listener on a journey to a big pay off at the end. That's a good structure when you already have the audience' attention and you want to keep them in suspense with an interesting story. But in a professional setting, the stuff we talk about is rarely that spell-binding, and the main objective is usually to just transfer information. In that case, you're better off just cutting straight to the point and filling in the details afterward.

Comment: Followup: I gave the presentation Friday and the headline structure worked perfectly. One person stated early on that he had thought the meeting was about problems we needed to solve, so he was surprised/glad to learn it was about a working solution. So without listing the headline first, I think he would have taken everything I said as "Is he saying I have to learn this?" and had a much worse reaction. Thanks so much for helping me!

Comment: @Noumenon glad it worked out. Thanks for telling me! :)